# Why there is no listener in c#?

Tags: c#, java

In java, a lot of class support listener to callback, I think it is observer pattern. But n c#, I don't find any, why?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: ..also: Click me --->: [MSDN - INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx).

Comment: Have you looked at `IObservable<T>` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd990377.aspx

Answer (score 5):

C# supports first class functions in the form of [Delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Note that in your case [events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/awbftdfh.aspx) are the basis for listener style paradigms.

For example, a form:

```
public class Form1
[--snip--]
    public event EventHandler Closed;
    public event EventHandler Clicked;
```

And another class that wants to modify that form:

```
public class Other
{
    public static void CloseHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Closed");
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Form1 form = new Form1();
        form.OnClose += CloseHandler;
        form.OnClick += (s,e) => Console.WriteLine("Click");
    }
}
```

This (barring syntax errors) should print "Closed" to the console when the form is closed. And "Click" when the form is clicked. Note that I am excluding the code that does the calling to keep it simple.

Also note that events in C# typically are named as present tense for interrupting events (happen right before the action) and past tense for post events (happen right after the action). You also typically have an OnClosed or similar to allow inheriting classes to override functionality without attaching an event, not to mention allowing a central place to avoid null problems.

Comment: That's not what Listener and Observer are about in Java.  They're more for events rather than asynch, first-class functions.

Comment: Indeed.  Why implement a heavyweight design pattern when the language implements it as a feature?

Comment: C# also has built-in syntax features for [events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/awbftdfh.aspx) built on top of delegates.

Comment: @duffymo: Events rely extensively on the delegate functionaly, I will update the answer to reflect that better though.

Answer (score 5):

C# replaced explicit `Listener` types with [events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8627sbea.aspx) which allow clients to register a callback of a given type. More recently, the [Reactive Extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609.aspx) library has implemented the observer pattern allowing events to be transformed, filtered etc. using Linq.

Answer (score 4):

C# uses delegates and events and lambda expressions, which allow vastly superior patterns.

Comment: How are events tied to delegates?  I'm ignorant.  I see from other comments that events are tied to delegates as callbacks.  I'll have to dig deeper.

Comment: Events are just a syntax feature that use delegates internally. You make an event by specifying the event handler (the delegate) and you call that event handler when raising the event (which just calls all the stored delegates).

Answer (score 3):

Well... to list to callbacks in C# you have [Delegates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288459%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), [Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) and [Lambda Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx) that replace Java listeners acting as first class functions and allowing a better quality of coding patterns. Recently, Linq [Reactive Extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577611.aspx) have been introduced giving even more tools for developers.